# VS Code C++ prints nothing on terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm new to C++ and VSCode, I'm following some online tutorials. I'm trying to make a hello world program, everything works fine, but there is not output on terminal.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

And the task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Built with GCC 13.2.0",
            "command": "c:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-std=c++20",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\build.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "c:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: \"c:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

On terminal: `.\build.exe` is executed without problems, but not printing.

Comment: Try double-clicking the exe in the explorer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat a terminal popups (opens and closes instantly).

Comment: Just download [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

Comment: `C++ doesn't print nothing` : what does it print? random text?

Comment: @rioV8 Looks like just a bad translation to me. In some languages (e.g. Russian) you'd have this kind of double negation when trying to say "doesn't print anything".

Comment: Title corrected @rioV8

Comment: From your compiler install paths, you did not follow the official tutorial: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) You may still want to do this for 2 reasons: 1: `msys2` makes it much easier to install dependent libraries and 2: You will learn what the 3 important json files are which will be important as you will need to modify your tasks.json once your code has more than 1 source file. I don't recommend code-runner for projects with more than 1 source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it seems to work.

I started to code just after VSCode installation. Now, I closed VSCode, reopened, and code works.